# How integrate custom auth-server with existing spring web application server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implement lots of example for spring boot single sign on integration.  but all example is redirect auth-server url for login .  so we are not need this auth-form-login from front-end.  we need front end user login with app and his authentication   is done by auth-server from a (app)server to (auth-server)server call.

I have already seen lots of example that used :

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableOAuth2Client
```

using example https://github.com/ecovaci/oauth2example

but i have not achieve my requirements like this image :- [auth-server background process from app login view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zgsi.png)

Comment: in what part you got the problem? what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Hi @lakshman, thanks to response , Actually i am usiing this example https://github.com/ecovaci/oauth2example but its redirect auth-server for login because its client property file used redirect-uri . so can it possible i have login from app view without redirect auth-server url (because we want to handle token athenticate on backend)